# How to compare day of the week with actual date in moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm relatively new to moment js. And I have a problem with the concept of time manipulation and comparison in moment JS. What I want to do is compare times of 2 events.

First event is an actual event, like work hours. This has a start and end time.

Second event is a re-occurring event, like overtime hours for a company. This also has a start time and end time, but the days may vary.

For example: from Monday 11:00PM to Tuesday 7:00AM is considered "overtime". But I worked from Monday 9:00PM to Tuesday 6:00AM.

How would i go about comparing these times? I need to compare them and separate the "overtime hours" from the "normal hours" and use these later.

Answer (score 1):

Moment offers [getter and setter methods](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) to access certain parameters for comparison. Here is a basic approach to check if overhours and events happen on the same day of the week:

```
if (moment(overhourDate).weekday() === moment(eventDate).weekday()) { 
    whatever(); 
}
```